# Azure Logic App - HTTP Post API responds without body

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Does anyone knows why when I use azure logic app in conjunction with an http API call I get the answer without a body only with the OUTPUTS option.

Download (Alt/Option + click)..

from Logic App : (no data)

[image]

from postman (work!)

[image]

I am trying to work with defender for cloud app API.

Comment: The body is still there, you just can’t see it directly in the response pane.

This can (typically) happen when the response isn’t strongly typed or the response is too large. Your situation looks a little different though. Not 100% sure.

You can still use the body expression though, it will still work.

Comment: Thanks you Brian.... do you know how I can do what you suggest?

Comment: Use the `body` expression, e.g.  `body('HTTP')` ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#body

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Logic App - HTTP Post API responds without body

I do agree with @Skin that this situation occurs when the response is **Strongly Typed** or if the response is too large that the Logic apps cannot show us in UI(Portal), but you can still use the properties of JSON as a body like below as `body('HTTP')`:

[image]

[image]

This type of situation occurs when we do not use correct filters on body. And I can also observe that there is a / missing at end of the URL in Logic app as compared to Postman.